# Rational Canonical Form Confusion; Choosing Basis Which Gives the Rational Canonical Form.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

I am reading the theory of finitely generated modules over a PID.
One of the applications of the the theory is that one can derive the theory of rational canonical form of a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space.

I considered the following question:

> ***Question.*** Given a linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, find a basis of $V$ with respect to which the matrix of $T$ is in the rational canonical form.

While attempting to solve this, I "proved" that given any basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ of $V$, there exist positive integers $k$ and $d_{k+1},\ldots,d_n$ such that
$$
(v_{k+1},Tv_{k+1},\ldots,T^{d_{k+1}-1}v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n,Tv_n,\ldots,T^{d_n-1}v_n)
$$
forms a basis of $V$.

This seems bizarre. But I can't find a mistake in my working.

I am sorry for the long post.

**Notations and Some Standard Things:**

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $T$ be a linear operator on $V$.
Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be a basis for $V$.
We give $V$ a $F[x]$ module structure by defining
$$p(x)\cdot(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n)=a_1p(T)v_1+\cdots+a_np(T)v_n$$
for all $a_i\in F$ and $p(x)\in F[x]$.
Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ be the standard basis of $F[x]^n$ as an $F[x]$-module.
Define a map $f:F[x]^n\to V$ as
$$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^np_i(x)e_i\right)=p_1(T)v_1+\cdots+p_n(T)v_n$$
It is easy to see that $f$ is an $F[x]$-module homomorphism.
Since $F[x]^n$ is a free module over a principal ideal domain, $\ker(f)$ too is a free $F[x]$-module of finite rank.
In fact, the rank of $\ker(f)$ is also $n$. 
(If it weren't then the dimension of $F[x]^n/\ker(f)$ as an $F$-vector space would be infinite while the dimension of $V$, which is isomorphic to $F[x]^n/K$ as an $F$-vector space, is finite.)
It is also known by Structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID that 
$$K=(F[x]e_1+\cdots+F[x]e_k)+(F[x]a_{k+1}(x)e_{k+1}+\cdots+F[x]a_n(x)e_n)$$
for some $1\leq k\leq j$ and each $a_i$ is a polynomial of degree at least $1$.
Define a map 
$$
 \varphi:F[x]^n\longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i=k+1}^n F[x]/\langle a_{i}(x)\rangle
$$
as
$$
 \varphi\left(\sum_{j=1}^np_j(x)e_j\right)=(\bar p_{k+1}(x),\ldots,\bar p_n(x))
$$
It is easily seen that $\varphi$ is an $F[x]$-module homomorphism whose kernel is precisely $\ker(f)$.
Let $\pi:F[x]^n\to F[x]^n/\ker(f)$ be the canonical projection homomorphism and $\bar f:F[x]^n/\ker(f)\to V$ and $\bar \varphi:F[x]^n/\ker \varphi\longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i=k+1}^n F[x]/\langle a_i(x)\rangle$ be the isomorphisms such that $f=\bar f\circ \pi$ and $\varphi=\bar\varphi\circ \pi$.
Thus we have an $F[x]$-module isomorphism 
$$\bar f\circ\bar\varphi^{-1}:\bigoplus_{i=k+1}^nF[x]/\langle a_i(x)\rangle\to V$$
which explicitly reads
$$\bar f\circ \bar\varphi^{-1}(\bar p_{k+1}(x),\ldots,\bar p_n(x))=p_{k+1}(T)v_{k+1}+\cdots+p_n(T)v_n$$
Since $\bar f\circ\bar \varphi^{-1}$ is an $F[x]$-module isomorphism, it is also an isomorphism $\bigoplus_{i=k+1}^nF[x]/\langle a_i(x)\rangle$ and $V$ as $F$-vector spaces.

**The Confusion:**

So a basis of $\bigoplus_{i=k+1}^nF[x]/\langle a_i(x)\rangle$ is mapped to a basis of $V$ via $\bar f\circ\bar \varphi^{-1}$.
Say $\deg a_i(x)=d_i$.
Then for each $k+1\leq i\leq n$, we can choose the basis $\mathcal B_i=(\bar 1,\bar x,\ldots,\bar x^{d_i-1})$ for $F[x]/\langle a_i(x)\rangle$.
We can thus form a basis $\mathcal B=(\mathcal B_{k+1},\ldots,\mathcal B_n)$ for $\bigoplus_{i=k+1}^nF[x]/\langle a_i(x)\rangle$.
Operating $\bar f\circ\bar \varphi^{-1}$ to the elements of $\mathcal B$, we get a basis $\mathcal B'$ of $V$ which reads
$$\mathcal B'=(v_{k+1},Tv_{k+1},\ldots,T^{d_{k+1}-1}v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n,Tv_n,\ldots,T^{d_n-1}v_n)$$

It also seems that the above basis is a basis with respect to which the matrix of $T$ is in the rational canonical form.

Can anybody see where have I made a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

I am wrong when I say that $$\ker f= (F[x]e_1+\cdots+F[x]e_k)+(F[x]a_1(x)e_{k+1}+\cdots+F[x]a_{n}(x)e_n)$$

There *exists* a basis $(e_1',\ldots,e_n')$ of $F[x]^n$ for which

$$
\ker f= (F[x]e_1'+\cdots+F[x]e_k')+(F[x]a_1(x)e_{k+1}'+\cdots+F[x]a_{n}(x)e_n')
$$

But that basis need not be $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$.